# Using inheritance with multiple files in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby . I  have a question with respect to using Inheritence in Ruby .

I have a class called as Doggy inside a file named Doggy.rb

```
class Doggy
  def bark
    puts "Vicky is barking"
  end
end
```

I have written another class named Puppy in another file named puppy.rb

```
class Puppy < Doggy
end

puts Doggy.new.bark
```

I am getting this Error:

```
Puppy.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Doggy (NameError)
```

Is it mandatory to have these classes (Doggy and Puppy ) inside a single file only?

Edited

As per the suggestions , i have tried using require and require_relative as shown , but still i am getting below Error

```
Puppy.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Doggy (NameError)

    class Puppy < Doggy
    end
    require_relative 'Doggy.rb'
    puts Doggy.new.bark
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes to be done in **puppy.rb** file
Assuming both files are in the same directory, you're expected to require the file in the following way:

doggy.rb

```
class Doggy
  def bark
    puts "Vicky is barking"
  end
end
```

puppy.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../doggy.rb', __FILE__)
class Puppy < Doggy
end

puts Doggy.new.bark
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ankit , its working now .

Its working with both require File.expand_path('doggy.rb') as well as with 
require File.expand_path('../doggy.rb', __FILE__) , could you please tell me whats the difference between those ?

Comment: In current scenario both will work same... but wanted to give an idea if you have some file in your subdirectory how you can require. For eg if 'doggy.rb' was in `animal/doggy.rb` than `File.expand_path('doggy.rb')` will fail and you have to do `File.expand_path('../animal/doggy.rb', __FILE__)`

Comment: Rather than File.expand_path I'd probably do something like `$: << '.'` if on an Unix-like system, not sure right now how the windows equivalent looks like.

Answer (score 5):

You should require file with `Doggy` class in it from file where `Puppy` is. Put

```
require './doggy'
```

or, if you are on ruby-1.9:

```
require_relative 'doggy'
```

in `puppy.rb` (assuming file names are doggy.rb and puppy.rb).

Answer (score 1):

Also, in addition to what everyone else has said, `puts Dog.new.bark` will always fail, because your class is not called **Dog**, it's *Doggy*. Beware.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary, you have to require the file where `Doggy` is declared. You can use [require](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require) or [require_relative](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative).

Then, anyway make sure you use the name you declared: `Doggy` and not `Dog`.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the file containing the definition of `Doggy`, *after* you inherit from `Doggy`. Of course, that *cannot possibly work*. How can you inherit from `Doggy` on line 1 if you only load the file containing the definition of `Doggy` on line 3?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include Doggy.rb in you Puppy class